# Instantiating module name with define macro

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am trying to instantiate a verilog module multiple times with different instance name such that it depend on a Macro definition. It is something like this

```
`define CHAN_NO 0
mymodule #(.chan_no(`CHAN_NO)) inst<CHAN_NO> (
    .Addr     (ADDR_A  )
   ,.Data     (DATA_A  )
   ,.Clk      (CLK     )
   );
```

of course this is a simplified example because instantiation and macro come from different files.
Is this possible , if yes what is right way of doing such instantiation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it is possible. You should use generate block:

```
genvar i;
generate
    for (i = 0; i < `CHAN_NO; i=i+1) 
    begin : mymodule_instance
        mymodule #(.chan_no(i)) mymodule_inst (
            .Addr     (ADDR_A  )
           ,.Data     (DATA_A  )
           ,.Clk      (CLK     )
       );
    end
endgenerate
```

After elaboration tree should look like this (for example CHAN_NO = 3):

```
mymodule_instance[0]
   mymodule_inst
mymodule_instance[1]
   mymodule_inst
mymodule_instance[2]
   mymodule_inst
```

**Edit:**
If you want to have an instance name that is dependent on macro then you can do it like this:

```
`define INSTANCE_NUM 0       
`define INSTANCE_NAME(x) instance_name``x``
    mymodule #(.chan_no(`INSTANCE_NUM)) `INSTANCE_NAME(`INSTANCE_NUM) (
      .Addr     (ADDR_A  )
     ,.Data     (DATA_A  )
     ,.Clk      (CLK     )
    );
```